# For strings, how do I remove repeated characters?

Tags: c++, string

My desired string manipulation procedure: If there is more than one consecutive instance of a character, retain only the first letter. Given "Steelsmith", delete the first "e", leaving the string "Stelsmith".

Here is my algorithim:

```
void replace(string s)
{
    int length = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
    {
        if (s[i] == s[i + 1])
        {
            s.erase(1+i);

        }

    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

When I input "Steelsmith", the output is "Ste", so it deletes the second 'e', along with the rest of the string. How do I retain the rest of the original string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can code it like this using the built in methods:

```
s.erase(std::unique(s.begin(), s.end()), s.end());
```

Comment: I just tested it out, it outputted Stelsmith.

Answer (score 1):

Use the form: `string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos);`

The arguments are position and length:

```
s.erase( i+1 , 1 ) ;
```

You can see it in action here: http://ideone.com/GhWoi0